# DI not working in ViewModel in MVC project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container, service-locator

So, I've made an mvc project that uses Unity for DI, the controller works perfectly with DI, but my viewmodels don't. I had this problem like 10 years ago but can't remember exactly how to fix it. Only remember I combined Service Locator and Unity to make it work.
So, problem happens when I do a postback on an edit page of one of my views. It tries to create the viewmodel, but it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. DI is supposed to fix this problem. Probably doing something wrong, but after searching on the web for an hour, I came up empty. Below is the code I added to my Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IVenturaRepository, TestRepository>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Below are my 2 constructors in my viewmodel:

```
public DeliveryEditViewModel(IVenturaRepository repository) : base(repository, new DeliveryViewModel()) { }
public DeliveryEditViewModel(IVenturaRepository repository, DeliveryViewModel model) : base(repository, model)
```

And my controller:

```
public BaseController(IVenturaRepository repository)
```

Last few lines of the stacktrace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Er is geen parameterloze constructor voor dit object opgegeven.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Please be sure you are using the correct tags, unity3d has nothing to do with unity-container

Comment: Please check out [MCVE] guidance on posting code. In this case please show real sensible container initialization (`container.RegisterType(new PerResolveLifetimeManager())` is clearly random concatenation of some pieces of code for example). Also you are showing view models, but exception is about binding hence need to know you action's parameters and corresponding types... And view models you return from action are rarely created via DI as they should not need any dependencies as views ideally don't have complex logic...

Comment: and as @ScottChamberlain said you proper tags - there is no service-locator usage anywhere in the post, "model-view-controller" is unrelated to "asp.net mvc" and should not be used for such questions...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The code you mentioned isn't random at all. It registers `TestRepository` as the implementation for `IVenturaRepository` using a specific lifetime manager. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649835.aspx. (Ah well, ignore this. I didn't check the edit history)

Comment: Before the question was edited it appeared as `RegisterType(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())`.

Comment: @Dirk I see - I should have edited post to see what they meant, but it already looked like code... The rest of my comment still apply so.

Comment: Is the Unity.Mvc bootstrapper also part of the project?

Comment: Your view-models shouldn't have dependencies injected into them. They should merely model the data that comes in and out of your views. If you insist, you should note that the `DependencyResolver` isn't involved in the model-binding process, you'll have to override the `DefaultModelBinder` and internally consult `DependencyResolver` to construct the model.

Comment: When my viewmodel is constructed by the controller, it has all the data I need in it. Problem is, after a postback, the model is constructed before it reaches the controller and by default it is using a default parameterless constructor. So without using the service locator or violating some oo principle, I have no way of achieving this.  As for asp.net mvc tag, I never used it in my final post. I used the service-locator tag as I remembered it using it many years ago, but couldn't remember the implementation, which I DID mention in my post...

Comment: The answer from haim770 was the most useful to me. But came up with a solution where I don't have to make use of ioc or overriding the modelbinder. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I needed a collection of items that I retrieved from my unity container, in my viewmodel. But then realized, I don't need that collection at the time the viewmodel was being constructed, I just needed the id one of them. So gave up on it and tried another approach that doesn't violate the oo principle or needs custom modelbinding.